# What can be planted at this time of year in a greenhouse (in the UK)?

Tags: greenhouse, planting-times

Normally we plant tomatoes and cucumber in our greenhouse during the summer here in the UK. We didn't do so this year, but I was wondering what could be planted in a greenhouse, if there is anything, for the winter months? The greenhouse isn't heated, it's just a glass structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite a bit of stuff actually, even in Scotland, but a lot of it will need to be sown inside or somewhere heated at this time of year up there, it being that much cooler than us here in London. Also, some vegetable crops can be germinated and started into growth now, but will simply sit, protected, in the greenhouse, until spring, when the weather warms up and light levels increase.

Have a look at this: [Vegetables to grow in winter: a how-to guide](http://www.permaculture.co.uk/articles/vegetables-grow-winter-how-guide). (Janet Renouf-Miller, via permaculture.co.uk, 2010).

Bear in mind that things like spinach, land cress and lambs lettuce will grow outside all winter too, but you’ll get more growth under cover, specially if you use polypropylene floating mulch in the pots. The article I’m directing you to is actually written by someone who lives in Scotland.

Comment: to make a hyperlink: go to the website you want and copy the address from the top of the browser bar. Then go to your post and click and continue to press the right mouse button and drag to select the text you want to show in blue as a hyperlink.  Then look at the menu at the top where you type for a small icon that looks like a chain from an anchor.  Developers think this is obvious just like those highway signs with no words...  Click on the icon and a little window will pop up.  Paste your link in with CTRL V and press OK, job done!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation K - I just hope I remember it all, seems quite complicated to me, and your comment about software developers is spot on - my son is one, so they assume you know what they mean, infuriatingly. Perhaps they just don't make good teachers...

Comment: just practice and you will have your own web site in no time!

Comment: (if you happen to notice the edit history of this post. There is a bug in revision rollbacks that we're working on with the team here at SE. Relevant meta post here: [error when trying to rollback a revision](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194018))

Comment: ah, I wondered why I couldn't get at it - for a start Spring should be spelt with a capital S...

Comment: @Bamboo, seasons are only capitalized at the start of the sentence and as a part of formal name of something (such as “Games of Winter Olympiad”/“Winter Olympics”). That’s just grammar.

Comment: Hmm, well maybe you're an American, the Ug, where the rules of grammar, not to mention vocabulary, are different. In classic English, the seasons are always capitalized. That explains why my friend from the US had to restudy and resit English before going to uni over here....

Comment: @Bamboo, at least one UK-based style guide thinks different: http://www.theguardian.com/styleguide/s Only capitalized as part of proper name, or if personified (as in poetry). What would be British equivalents of Chicago Manual of Style etc.?

Comment: Not a clue, 'style' type publications are not on my reading list, ever. All I can tell you is, you'll be marked down in an English A level examination if you don't capitalize those season names wherever they appear. I'll freely admit I don't always bother in my own personal communications though...